# API for monitoring AWS lambda and other instances pricing in real time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

I am looking for a programmatic way to monitor my lambda serverless environment cost in real time, or x hours retrospective. I am looking at the budget API but it seems like it always goes around a defined budget which is not my use case. The other way I thought might work is the count lambda executions and calculate according to lambda instance type. Any insight or direction how to go about this programmatically would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Using the AWS Cost Explorer API - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-api.html):

> The **Cost Explorer API** allows you to programmatically query your cost and usage data. You can query for aggregated data such as total monthly costs or total daily usage. You can also query for granular data, such as the number of daily write operations for DynamoDB database tables in your production environment.

Cost Explorer refreshes your cost data at least once every 24 hours, so it isn't "real-time".